# How to sort a list

Tags: selenium

I need to check if the list is in alphabetical order. SysPrint seems like that the list is in alphabetical order, but assertion throws an error that the list is NOT in alphabetical order. Any help is greatly appreciated!

java.lang.AssertionError: Advertiser is not in alphabetical order. expected [true] but found [false]".

My Script:

```
try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        List<String> displayed = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> sorted = new ArrayList<String>();

        List<WebElement> verifyAdvertiser = wait
                .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By
                        .xpath(".//*[@id='basic']/div[4]/table/tbody[2]/tr")));
        System.out.println("NUMBER OF ROWS IN THIS TABLE = "
                + verifyAdvertiser.size());

        for (WebElement element : verifyAdvertiser) {
            System.out.println("" + element.getText());
            displayed.add(element.getText());
            sorted.add(element.getText());
        }

        Collections.sort(sorted);
        log.info(sorted);

        if (!displayed.equals(sorted)) {

            final String failedMsg = "Advertiser is not in alphabetical order.";
            log.error(failedMsg, null);
            boolean passed = false;
            Assert.assertTrue(passed, failedMsg);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        final String failedMsg = "Failed trying to check agency names in alphabetical order.";
        log.error(failedMsg, e);
        boolean passed = false;
        Assert.assertTrue(passed, failedMsg);
    }
```

Comment: `!displayed.equals(sorted)` is "if the collection changed" which is expected. Then `boolean passed = false;` followed by an `assertTrue()` call on said `false`. Your logic is flawed, your program does something different than you describe. Go over it, again, mainly via the lines I highlighted. I bet the `sorted` list is actually sorted.

Comment: assertFalse() fixed it!